# what is the roles of folder www, page, src in an ionic project?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new in ionic. I found in some ionic project, there is no src(app & pages) folder, but only is www folder. 
After checking some sample ionic projects, it seems the src folder contents the similar components as www folder.

Could you please explain the differences between these folders, are they can be used together? If there is some detailed introduction for ionic framework architecture, it will be really appreciated.

Comment: How did you started your project? And what Angular-Version do you use?

Comment: It may due to the different versions of angular or ionic that you use. Can you specify the version of these two here?

Comment: what are the roles of src and www folders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `src` folder contains your raw, uncompiled code, the files you need to edit in order to build your app. It'll hold all your pages, components, pipes, services, themes, assets, images.

The `www` is simply your compiled code, every time you build your project the www content is erased and built again, so there's no need to change anything in this folder. If you want to deploy for web one of the ways is using the code that's inside www folder.

The project you've found with no src folder must be an early version of ionic 2, i remember ionic 2 rc6 was already using src folder, so this project is using a version released before November 2016.

You can learn more about the structure [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/tutorial/project-structure/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have a project which only has www folder and I am just changing the files inside www and then build for android or ios platform. Do you mean www is the compiling result of src?

Comment: @affeto Yes, i the new projects www is the compiling results of src, in older projects i don't know how it works. If you want to convert the older project to a newer version in the ionic changelog on github there's a tutorial of how you can do this. Don't forget to mark as correct if my answer helped :D

Comment: Thanks ^^, where is the tutorial?

Comment: You've just upvoted, you need to mark the correct sign. And here's the tutorial https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc0-2016-09-28
But it's a lot of work to change everything from the earlier ionic 2 to the newest ionic 3, maybe it's worth creating a new project and copy/past your code to the new project, of course if it's not a big project.