# How can I understand the "WWW" folder in Ionic project?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

I need help understanding the project structure of a project made with Ionic. 
Normally I have learnt from tutorials that a project with Ionic has `src` folder where we can find components, services. but in this projects, I have only a `www` folder and I have no idea what it is and how can I analyse its code.
I have seen this answer in this post but still didn't get it very well, it says that `www` folder is generated after building the project :

[what is the roles of folder www, page, src in an ionic project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164473/what-is-the-roles-of-folder-www-page-src-in-an-ionic-project)

So my question exactly is how can I understand an Ionic project that has only `www` folder.

Is it necessary to have the `src` folder to make modifications on it?
Any help will be appreciated, I'm really stuck here.

Thanks.

Here is my project structure:

[image]

Comment: can you include a pic of the directory tree?

Comment: i tried but unfortunately the stack overflow tell me i don't have the permission to post pictures yet. my account still new

Comment: just do it without clicking the picture button.  Copy your image to the clipboard. Go to www.imgur.com   paste it there, get a link, and paste the link into your question or comment

Comment: for example, you can comment on your question as you have, and in a comment you can  include a link like https://i.imgur.com/WySYKxr.png  and thereis probably nothing stopping you pasting a link like that into your question

Comment: i understand, here is it i have put the picture in the post

Comment: there's no src directory?  I guess there's a program somewhere that starts up a web server. The  contents of the www directory would  be  accessible from the web server,  and by you locally.  I read that "Ionic is both a CSS framework and a Javascript UI library. It is built on top of AngularJS".   AngularJS is a javascript framework. So you'd do all your programming within the www directory. Like you would if all you were doing was javascript and HTML